# Effect of charger on laptop touchpad

Tags: charger, touch-panel

A few years ago, on my previous laptop Toshiba R830, I had a problem with my touchpad.
The cursor was lagging and touchpad was not working properly.
I then realized that my touchpad was affected by the charger. When the charger was disconnected, touch pad was working well.

On my charger circuit I found a capacitor that was connecting the ground net of output at isolated circuit after secondary winding to the primary part of circuit.

The capacitor has few nF capacity and has no effect on the function of charger because feedback signal is fed back trough an optocoupler and nothing more is needed.

This capacitor make the output circuit to be not suspended.

When I removed this capacitor, it made my touchpad worse.

I then replaced that capacitor with a higher capacitance say 10 or 22 nF one and it solved my problem.
The touchpad then worked properly.

Now I have a Dell E5470 laptop. My touch pad rarely lags and cursor is sometimes fixed on screen for a little time.

I then used an other charger that was not original and made it worse but I still have problem with its own charger.

People on Dell.com asked this question and Dell.com just asked them to turn off gestures.

https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/Dell-Latitude-E5470-touchpad-lags-freezes-pauses-issues/td-p/6108926

I did the same trick and replaced the capacitor with a new more capacitance one but didn't help. I then connected two series capacitor with input AC and connected their junction to the ground but problem persisted.

Paralleling a 100 nF cap with output, an other capacitor on high voltage capacitor at input, using output or input wire with ferrite bead didn't help.

No newer driver is also available and latest driver is installed.

Could any one make it clear how that capacitor solved the previous one and how exactly a touchpad works and affected by charger?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using a charger with ungrounded or grounded mains plug? If it is grounded plug, is it connected to a grounded outlet?

Comment: I rarely encounter this problem even when my laptop is not connected to charger.
Connecting to a grounded outlet decrease this problem.
Any connection between laptop and for example an oscilloscope card like Hantek 6220 or connecting a programmer to a device make this problem happen with no charger. but many laptops have no such problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively common issue. Best addressed with chargers that actually have a protective ground (third terminal) that connects to the ground of the wall socket. Then shielding and metal parts (heat sink) inside of the PSU have a grounding path. If floating (as you tested with the capacitor removed) the secondary circuit may have too much common mode noise and the touch pad (due to it's nature of capacitive sensing) may not handle this well.

I resolved this issue once by a common mode ferrite core on the output DC cable to the laptop (large "bead" in plastic housing that can be clamped around the cable).
In another case connection to a printer over USB created sufficient ground path so the computer wasn't at HF potential - but that was a (pleasant) side effect and not a true solution.

OEM power supply shouldn't cause this issue. All of the occasions I saw were when using a (cheap) replacement power supply. That may make you wonder what else may go wrong since such PSU most likely didn't pass rigorous EMI and safety testing(?)

I see that one of your chargers is original (OEM) Dell. DELL chargers - in most cases - have a grounding (third) wire at the AC side. Is your socket grounded?

Comment: A grounded outlet decrease the problem but even with no charger with connecting oscilloscope card or any device increase the problem or make touchpad unusable.
Most of time I have no problem with no charger and no connecting device but even with no charger and no connected device on some tables this problem sometimes occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Bad idea.

You just modified a UL-listed charging block *that interacts with AC power*.  That voided the UL listing, violated NEC 110.2 and 110.3, and made the charging block unsafe.

In AC, capacitors limit current.  That capacitor was sized as a compromise between clean power and assuring that leakage current is not lethal in any likely failure mode of the power supply.

You can always stick inline (plug-in) surge suppressors in between the charging block and the AC socket in the wall, and see if that helps.